# Access same url with different Controller and method for API

Tags: php, laravel, url, http-headers

I am currently working on API in laravel 5.6 and I would like versioning for APIs like v1 and v2.

my problem is I want to run one URL and access both API version, I am passing version number into HEADER and access API controller according to the version number. I am also using middle ware to check version number but not getting what I need.

Here is my **web.php**

```
Route::post('/api/getticktes/{id}', 'Api\v1\TicketController@show')->middleware('checkHeaderV1');
```

**Header** 
version :- v1
version :- v2

My controller directory is

```
Controller
 -Api
  --v1
  ---TicketController.php
  --v2
 ---TicketController.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class, i have used it in my old project, may be it is not the efficient way but it will work

ApiVersion class

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiVersion
{
    protected static $valid_api_versions = [
        1 => 'v1',
        2 => 'v2'
    ];


    protected static function get($request)
    {
        $allApiVersions = array_keys(self::$valid_api_versions);
        $latestVersion = $allApiVersions[count($allApiVersions) - 1];
        $apiVersion = $request->header('api-version', $latestVersion);
        return in_array($apiVersion, $allApiVersions) ? $apiVersion : $latestVersion;
    }

    protected static function getNamespace($apiVersion)
    {
        return 'Api\\' . self::$valid_api_versions[$apiVersion];
    }

    public static function versionNamespace()
    {
       $request = Request::capture();
       return $apiNamespace = ApiVersion::getNamespace(self::get($request));
    }
}
```

Now use this middleware in api routes file for `namespace`

//API routes

```
$versionNameSpace = ApiVersion::versionNamespace();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['api'], 'namespace' => "{$versionNameSpace}"], function () {

});
```

Add `api-version` in your request header. The value should be 1 or 2 etc

Comment: What is $versionNameSpace and how to pass it, is it header value??

Comment: `$versionNameSpace` is the folder name inside `Api` folder. When you add `api-version` header value to 1 then the namespace of controller will be `Api\v1`

Comment: check `$valid_api_versions` array in `ApiVersion` class. Better if you use `V1` instead `v1`

Comment: Can we achieve by checking version in web.php $version = Request::header('api-version'); and redirect to according to the version. is it right process??

Comment: redirect where ? you have to load controller based on version namespace. Did you  try my answer ?

Comment: yes i try your answer but it didn't work, always say "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: can you try printing `$versionNameSpace` what does it printing ?

Comment: Yes i print it, but nothing get into api.php

Comment: did you added request header in api call ?

Comment: I have add this code in api.php

$versionNameSpace = ApiVersion::handle();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api'], 'namespace' => "{$versionNameSpace}"], function () {
    Route::post('/api/getticktes/{id}', 'Api\v1\TicketController@show');
});

Comment: when you call the api that time you need to add  `api-version` request header

Comment: how are you passing version in header ?

Comment: Yes i am passing variable from header into postman 

api-version :- 2

Comment: let me try at my end

Comment: when i tested in my side it print `Api\v1` and i have set `api-version` in header with value 1

Comment: i have updated answer try it now, it will return you namespace with version